# Do I have to add the OPTIONS method when enable CORS for an HTTP API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, curl, aws-api-gateway, aws-api-gateway-v2

My situation:

I have an HTTP API working with AWS Lambda proxy Integrations in API Gateway, with GET and POST methods.
I want to enable CORST for it.

Doubt, do I have to add the OPTIONS method to Access-Control-Allow-Methods?
In the **HTTP APIs** documentation, I remark **HTTP APIs** not REST APIs:
[It is specified](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-cors.html#:%7E:text=AWS%20Glossary-,Configuring%20CORS%20for%20an%20HTTP%20API,-PDF):
That if you configure CORS API Gateway it will automatically return the a response to preliminary OPTIONS requests even if you don't have OPTIONS routes.

> Does that mean, I have to add the OPTIONS method to Access-Control-Allow-Methos for it to work correctly or not?

What I tried:

If I do not enable CORS:

```
In the frontend. when making a GET request I receive an CORS error during the preliminary OPTIONS request.
```

If I enable CORS without adding OPTIONS to Acces-Control-Allow-Methods:

```
* On the fronted. When making a GET request, it works correctly. In the header of the OPTIONS response I receive Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST
* Performing curl from ubuntu. When I make the OPTIONS request I don't get back the ccess-Control-Allow-Method header. Code 204
```

If I enable CORS by adding OPTIONS to Access-Control-Allow-Methods:

```
It works the same way as above but on frontend obviously I also get OPTIONS apart from GET and POST.
```

What I expect to happen:

- That the forntend works correctly when performing the GET, that is to say that OPTIONS returns the desired headers.
- That the curl also returns them to me. I do not understand why it does not return them.